# Printing Data Received using POST Request to local server using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

So, apparently I am trying to send data from my openCV webcam to a local sever spun using Flask. I am able to receive the data and print it on terminal, however, I am not really sure as to how to print it on a webpage.

This is my program :

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response,request, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

# creating the flask app 
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response,request, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)



@app.route("/getData", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                textInput = request.form["data"]
                print(textInput)
                return render_template("text.html",text=textInput)
        else:
                return render_template("text.html")

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def contact():
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am sending data from webcam.py using requests module via post request. The data is received and currently printed on terminal. However, I want it to be redirected to text.html.

```
data = {"data": res} 
requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
```

The above is the code snippet I use to send data from webcam.py to API_ENDPOINT (127.0.0.1:5000/getData).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Sign to Speech</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            background-color: #FFC107
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

       <h4>{{text}}</h4>


</body>

</html>
```

The above is my text.html page under templates directory. 
Any Help will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you send data from `OpenCV webcam` to a `local server` and from `local server` you return a response to `openCV webcam` and that's why you see data in the terminal as you print it and you can't see data in the webpage of flask app as you don't have that data, because you have lost data at the moment you have returned a response to the `openCV webcam`.

In this case, you could use 1 of the 3 approaches.

1. Using a database, like `sqlite3` and save received data from the `openCV webcam`, but then you will need to do more, like create models and etc.
2. Save data received from `OpenCV webcam` to a file - quicker option to verify that everything works (the one I will use in my code example)
3. Using `flask.session` and saving data to flask session and then reading from it as you would read data from python dictionary.

In these cases, when you open your flask web app in the browser, you need to read data from either `DB`, `file` or `flask.session`.

In this example, I will use a file named `data.txt` to which I will write (I will use `a` that means open file to append to the end of a file, then the old data will be left when you will send multiple requests from `OpenCV webcam`) information received from `OpenCV webcam` server.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify

# creating the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/getData", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getInfo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text_input = request.form["data"]
        with open('data.txt', 'a') as data_file:
            data_file.write(text_input)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Data saved sucessfully!'}), 200
    else:
        text_input = None
        with open('data.txt', 'r') as data_file:
            text_input = data_file.read()
        return render_template("text.html", text=text_input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This way your `OpenCV webcam` will receive `200` response with a message. Then you can navigate to your web app `/getData` page, then the request method will be `GET` and then it will read the content of a file `data.txt` and will pass this to the webpage you have just opened.

> Make sure that you can access `data.txt`, it should be placed in the same directory as your app exists (at least with this example, but you should make more appropriate structure later on or at all use the `sqlite3` database for local development).

Comment: Hey, I tried using the same, however, for some reason my data isn't being redirected to /getData. 
It's being printed on the terminal though.

Comment: This surely does work, I completely forgot about the fact that my response is being sent back to openCV webcam. 
Thanks for the quick help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response,request, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

# creating the flask app 
app = Flask(__name__) 
# creating an API object 
api = Api(app) 

@app.route("/getData", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getInfo():
        textInput = request.form["data"]
        print(textInput)
        return render_template("text.html",text=textInput)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And in your HTML use Jinja like following below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ text }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using just render template as mentioned in my code rather than make_response ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using just render_template, However, the same problem persists. 
I guess my data is not being redirected to /getData

Comment: Nope, I am getting status 200, which means the data is being sent via POST correctly. 
May be some error with rendering the template ?